# Storing time specific data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I am looking for a good way to store time specific data in cassandra.

Each entry can look like `(start_time, value)`. Later, I would like to retrieve the current value.

Logic of retrieving current value is like following.

1. Find all rows with `start_time<=current_time`.
2. Then find the value with maximum `start_time` from the rows obtained in the first step.

PS:- Edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Is it the one query you want to execute ? List all type of query you want to execute and model your table from that

Comment: Yes, this is the only query I want to execute.

Comment: And you need all the previous data right ?

Comment: Yes, I need the most recent past data

Answer (score 1):

The exact requirements are not possible. But we can get close to it with one more column.

First, to be able to use `<=` operator, your `start_time` column need to be the clustering key of your table.

Then, you need a different partition key. You could choose a fixed value but it could bring problems when the partition will have too many rows. Then you should better use something like the year or the month of the `start_time`.

```
CREATE TABLE time_specific_table (
  year bigint,
  start_time timestamp,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY((year), start_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (start_time DESC);
```

The problem is that when you will query the table, you will need to know the value of the partition key :

> Find all rows with start_time<=current_time

```
SELECT * FROM time_specific_table
WHERE year = :year AND start_time <= :time;
```

> select the value with maximum start_time

```
SELECT * FROM time_specific_table
WHERE year = :year LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM time_specific_table
WHERE year = :year;` this part is not clear to me. How it will give me max start_time?

Comment: The queries I mentioned are not independent. Edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravi thanks to the `DESC` `CLUSTERING ORDER` on the on the `start_time` column, you will get the highest value of `start_time` with this query.

Comment: In fact I forgot someting. The data retreived is ordered by start_time descending. So the max value is only the first row of this result. I changed my response with a `LIMIT 1` clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Create two separate table like below :**

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    start_time timestamp,
    value int,
    PRIMARY KEY(start_time, value)
);

CREATE TABLE current_value (
    partition int PRIMARY KEY,
    value int
);
```

Now you have to insert data into both table, to insert data into second table use a static value like 1

```
INSERT INTO current_value(partition, value) VALUES(1, 10);
```

Now In current value table your data will be upsert and You will get latest value whenever you select.

Comment: @Ravi current_value table will keep the last insert

Comment: I Think that here the data table won't allow a query like start_time<=current_time.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Yes, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Ravi in your question you specify two logic. Both of them will perform worstly in cassandra.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam The queries I mentioned are not independent. Edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks.